# Animation to none white part of an image

Tags: android, android-animation, android-imageview, android-bitmap

I have 2 image, one is a sun and one is a line. I want to animate the sun from one end of the line to the other end of the line, pixel by pixel.

But for some reason it is animating to a random part in the white part of the picture.

I am using 2 image views and getting their bitmap representation and then going through it and retrieving the location of that pixels that are not white.

Here is my code:

On Create:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.testingzone);


    lineImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.line);
    sunImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.sun);


    lineImage.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    lineImage.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
            View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    lineImage.layout(0, 0, lineImage.getMeasuredWidth(), lineImage.getMeasuredHeight());
    lineImage.buildDrawingCache(true);
    getArray();

    sunImage.setY(pixelPlaceY[0]);
    sunImage.setX(pixelPlaceX[0]);

    testing();


}
```

2 Methods:
OnTouch:
     public void testing() {

```
    findViewById(R.id.testingZoneButtonRelativelayout).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {


        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {




            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                for (int i = 0; i < pixelAmount; i++) {

                    sunImage.animate().x(pixelPlaceX[i]).y(pixelPlaceY[i]).setDuration(5000);
                    Log.d("Pixel ", "X, Y: " + pixelPlaceX[i] + ", " + pixelPlaceY[i]);


                }

            }


            return true;
        }
    });

}
```

SetUp:

```
public void getArray() {


    pixelAmount = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i< lineImage.getWidth(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j< lineImage.getHeight(); j++){

            if(i < lineImage.getWidth() && j < lineImage.getWidth()) {
                int color = lineImage.getDrawingCache().getPixel(i, j);

                if (color != 0) {
                    pixelAmount++;
                    Log.d("Pixel Amount", "Amount"+ pixelAmount);
                }
            }
        }

    }

    pixelPlaceX = new int[pixelAmount];
    pixelPlaceY = new int[pixelAmount];
    int counter = 0;


    for (int i = 0; i < lineImage.getWidth(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < lineImage.getHeight(); j++) {

            int color = lineImage.getDrawingCache().getPixel(i, j);

            if (((color >> 24) & 0xff) != 0) {

                pixelPlaceX[counter] = i;
                pixelPlaceY[counter] = j;
                counter++;

                int A = (color >> 24) & 0xff; // or color >>> 24
                int R = (color >> 16) & 0xff;
                int G = (color >>  8) & 0xff;
                int B = (color      ) & 0xff;

                Log.d("Color:", "A " + A);
                Log.d("Color:", "R " + R);
                Log.d("Color:", "G " + G);
                Log.d("Color:", "B " + B);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

This is the 'sun' and the line, I want the sun to start at the beginning of the line and end at the end of the line

These are just photos for now ideally i want to make something like pictures 3 and 4. where it will follow the curved lines and move on it based on the time.

[image]

[image]

Comment: white color has non zero alpha that is why it is moving in white part.

Comment: and black has a 0 alpha? I thought it was the opposite

Comment: alpha is used for transparency. both black and white colors have non zero alpha. you need to determine the pixels of your line based on the RGB values

Comment: All my RGB colors are R:0 G:0 B:0 .....The only difference in any of the pixels is the alpha

Comment: can you add the images to the question

Comment: Sure, just did, thanks, I did resize the sun to be much smaller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147019/discussion-between-jay-pandya-and-edon-freiner).

Comment: sure, how do I start one?

Comment: click on the link above

Comment: I messaged you, Thanks